# Does it make sense to have max-age and s-maxage in the Cache-Control HTTP header?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers

Considering that max-age applies to all the caches, and s-maxage only applies to shared caches (proxy and gateway cache)....

**Does it make sense to use both directives in a non-expirable and public page?**

Controller pseudo-code:

```
w = Response();
w.setPublic();
w.setMaxAge("1 year");
w.setShareMaxAge("1 year");

return w;
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From [HTTP Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3):

> ## 14.9.3 Modifications of the Basic Expiration Mechanism
>
> ...
>
> #### s-maxage
>
> If a response includes an s-maxage directive, then for a shared cache (but not for a private cache), the maximum age specified by this directive **overrides** the maximum age specified by either the max-age directive or the Expires header.
>
> ...

Note, "**overrides**". So, it would only make sense if you intend to specify a different maximum age for shared caches as compared to `max-age`, which would be used by end users.

In your particular example, they're the same, so specifying `s-maxage` is just unnecessary.

Comment: I don't agree that it is unnecessary. A shared cache like a reverse proxy cache (i.e. varnish) may have a longer cache value than in private browser cache, because the web application behind varnish purges the content, but in browser one want to get more often the fresh version from the server. So it makes lots of sense if one want to provide user with latest content but want to get load off the page rendering backend.

Comment: For reverse proxies or other caches on servers, it can actually make sense to have shorter s-maxage than max-age. Private caches could keep older versions but requests from other users would be fresher. So it all comes down to what freshness is required for the content.

Comment: So given an object with this cache info `{"cache-control": "s-maxage=120, public", "etag": "w/12830-1542793456000", "last-modified": "wed, 21 nov 2018 09:44:16 gmt"}`, What is the correct freshness_time calculated by the **browser's cache**? Is it `120s` or `10%*(current-time - last-modified)`?

Comment: @jensens I think you misread BalusC's answer. It is unnecessary because both `s-maxage` and `max-age` values are the same. In this case the reverse proxy will use the same cache expiration delay even if you remove `s-maxage` (it will use `max-age` instead). Of course it's not unnecessary when the values are different!

Answer (score 13):

Key point to note in the definition is **share cache**

From [HTTP Header Field Definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3)

> ## 14.9.3 Modifications of the Basic Expiration Mechanism
>
> ...
>
> #### s-maxage
>
> If a response includes an s-maxage directive, then for a **shared cache** (but **not** for a **private cache**), the maximum age specified by this directive **overrides** the maximum age specified by either the max-age directive or the Expires header.
>
> ...

It means that reverse proxy/caches like varnish, cloudfront, cloudflare can have a cache age different to browser cache.
I would personally prefer value of `s-maxage` to be higher than `maxage`

In HTTP 1.1 once response is cached, you can't contact browser to invalidate cache but you can tell it to CDNs.

Comment: It's actually quite easy to invalidate browser caches by appending a querystring to the asset.

Comment: So given an object with this cache info `{"age": "2604", "cache-control": "public, s-maxage=2700", "last-modified": "thu, 26 mar 2020 18:32:56 gmt"}`, What is the correct freshness_time calculated by the **browser's cache**? Is it `2700-2604=96s` or `10%*(current-time - last-modified)`?