# S-maxage and maxage difference

Tags: http, caching

I need to understand,use of `s-maxage` header for caching, are there any example to help me understand in which cases i should use both `s-maxage` and `max-age`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does it make sense to have max-age and s-maxage in the Cache-Control HTTP header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971747/does-it-make-sense-to-have-max-age-and-s-maxage-in-the-cache-control-http-header)

Comment: Hi Joe, i know what does s-maxage, but i can't understand the situation, where i need to use both of them.

Answer (score 13):

As suggested by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971747/does-it-make-sense-to-have-max-age-and-s-maxage-in-the-cache-control-http-header#comment57407913_15972973):

> For reverse proxies or other caches on servers, it can actually make sense to have shorter `s-maxage` than `max-age`.

A reverse caching proxy will be able to serve the same resource to any number of clients for as long as `s-maxage`. The load on the proxy will increase with the number of clients, so it may be worth having the proxy's single check (`s-maxage`) be more frequent than the requests from downstream clients (e.g. browsers) (`max-age`).

To give a more concrete example: you might want to suggest that a CDN should check regularly (hourly) for an updated resource on an origin server. However, it may be fine for any end user to keep using the response they get for days; users with cold caches will get the updated version.