# Cache on Cloudfront for a year, but browser should revalidate every 24 hours

Tags: caching, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I have a JS asset which needs to be served from a fixed URL, so I can't use versioning. (Many different sites are already accessing it, and they can't be changed easily)

The file is sitting on AWS Cloudfront.

I would like the file to be cached in browsers for up to a year, but still revalidate every 24 hours. It is not vital to be exactly 24 hours. The file is being updated roughly every month.

I was thinking of using these headers:

```
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, stale-while-revalidate=6800
```

When a new version of the file is published to the CDN I could issue a Cache Invalidate command from Travis.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stale-while-revalidate`, which is now supported by CloudFront. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/05/amazon-cloudfront-stale-while-revalidate-stale-if-error-cache-control-directives/

Comment: Excellent, finally!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not clear on exactly what you're asking; the title says you want to cache in Cloudfront for a year, but the question itself says you "would like the file to be cached **in browsers** for up to a year".

If it's the former, you can use the `s-maxage` directive, which indicates how long a shared cache (like Cloudfront) can serve a response:

```
Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=3153600, max-age=86400, stale-while-revalidate=6800
```

If you really do mean that you "would like the file to be cached in browsers for up to a year, but still revalidate every 24 hours", then you may be misunderstanding how caching works. You can't control how long a cache stores something (other than `no-store`), you can only indicate how long it should consider a stored response to be fresh. So there's no way to tell the browser to store something for a year but only consider it fresh for 24 hours.

Comment: `stale-while-revalidate` seems not to be supported by CloudFront, at least I cannot find any hint in their documentation. The only directive in this regard is `stale-if-error` [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html) which has a different functionality and meaning

Comment: Maybe have a look at the Shared Cache headers `s-maxage` to cache stuff differently for users/browsers and CloudFront/CDN. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#s-maxage)

Comment: @mana: `stale-while-revalidate` is used by the browser, not CloudFront (and is copied directly from the OP). The question doesn't actually have anything to do with Coudfront, it's specifically asking about browser caching ("I would like the file to be cached **in browsers**...").

Comment: This is correct, but the browser has no need to revalidate if `cache-control: public, max-age=31536000` since the object will be valid for one year. Setting `cache-control: s-maxage=31536000, max-age=86400` should result in the required behaviour: caching for 1 year in CloudFront and 1 day in a browser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971747/does-it-make-sense-to-have-max-age-and-s-maxage-in-the-cache-control-http-header#comment57407913_15972973

Comment: @mana: I interpret the question differently. The title asks about caching on CloudFront for one year (which is what your headers address), but the question itself says "cached in browsers for up to a year, but still revalidate every 24 hours", which is what I address in my answer. Your interpretation of this ambiguous question is also reasonable, so you should just post a separate answer.